# Remove spaces between words only not between numbers

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string consist of words, special characters (*, |, ( etc.) and numbers(floating). I want to remove white spaces between only words and special characters. Spaces between numbers should not be removed. How I can do it in Perl?

E.g.:

`Rama 1 * 2.34 * ( L - 0.45 ) XYZ 10 20.05 30.06 40 P  >  25.`

It should be after conversion:

`Rama1*2.34*(L-0.45)XYZ 10 20.05 30.06 40 P>25.`

Comment: Hint: `\d` matches digits in a regular expression, `\D` matches non-digits

Comment: Then why there is a space in this `XYZ 10` and not in `Rama1` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<!\d)\h+|\h+(?!\d)
```

You can use `lookarounds` here.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uF4oY4/62

Answer (score 0):

You may use the below lookaround based regex.

```
perl -pe 's/\s+(?=\D)|(?<=\D)\s+//g' file
```

**Example:**

```
$ echo 'Rama 1 * 2.34 * ( L - 0.45 ) XYZ 10 20.05 30.06 40 P > 25.' | perl -pe 's/\s+(?=\D)|(?<=\D)\s+//g'
Rama1*2.34*(L-0.45)XYZ10 20.05 30.06 40P>25.
```

or

```
$ echo 'Rama 1 * 2.34 * ( L - 0.45 ) XYZ 10 20.05 30.06 40 P > 25.' | perl -pe 's/(?<=[^\s\w])\s+|\s+(?=[^\w\s])//g'
Rama 1*2.34*(L-0.45)XYZ 10 20.05 30.06 40 P>25.
```